# An inequality about quasi-linear function

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $\gamma$ be a positive, nondecreasing, continuous, function defined on $[0,\infty]$. Suppose that $\gamma(x+y)\le C(\gamma(x)+\gamma(y))$. In addition, suppose $$ \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dr}{\gamma(r)}=\infty.$$
suppose further that
$$
f(t)\le f(0)+\int_0^t\gamma(f(r))dr+\gamma \Big(\int_0^tf(r)dr\Big).
$$
How to show that
$$
\gamma(\int_0^t f(r)dr)\le C(t+1)\int_0^t \gamma(f(r))dr
$$

Actually, this question come from [lemma 1.2 in this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00205-013-0691-z).

**My effort:** Following the hint in this paper, I want to show that $\gamma$ cannot grow faster than $t^2$. However, I can't rule out the possibility that $$\limsup_{t\to +\infty}\frac{\gamma(t)}{t^2}=\infty.$$

I have no idea how to proceed it. Thanks for any help.

**Update:** If $C\le 1$, I can give a proof.
\begin{align*}
\gamma(\int_0^t f(r)dr)&=\gamma(\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{(k-1)t}{n}}^{\frac{kt}{n}}f(r)dr)\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}C^k\gamma(f(\xi_k))\frac{t}{n},\xi_k\in (\frac{k-1}{n}t,\frac{k}{n}t)
\end{align*}
If $C\le 1$, we can send $n$ to $\infty$ and get the proof. (Sorry. I find that the last inequality above this line is false. Because $\gamma(ax+by)\not \le a\gamma(x)+b\gamma(y)$)

In addition, we can get a upper bound of $\gamma$. In fact,
$$\gamma(2^n)\le 2C\gamma(2^{n-1})\le (2C)^n\gamma(1).$$
Using $\gamma$ is increasing, we have that
$$
\gamma(t)\le Ct^{1+\frac{\ln C}{\ln 2}}
$$

Comment: Well $\gamma$ cannot grow faster than quadratically as otherwise $\int_2^\infty1/\gamma$ would converge.

Comment: Sure. But I can't prove that $\gamma$ can be bounded by $Ct^2$ and don't know how to use it.

Comment: Is the constant $C$ in the hypothesis and the $C$ in the conclusion of the Lemma the same, or are they allowed to be different? This convention is sometimes used without mentioning it.

Comment: @SilverBlueZ Thanks you! They are allowed to be different.

Comment: It seems like you need some kind of linear growth bound from below, as you might be able to construct counterexamples for $\gamma(t) = t^{-1/2}$ using something along the lines of $f(x) = x^{-1}.$ If for instance $\gamma$ is (comparable to a) convex function and satisfies a quadratic growth condition (which I don't see how to prove), then the result would follow using Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @ktoi Thanks for your comments！ If $\gamma$ is convex, one can get $\gamma(\int_0^t f(r)dr)\le \frac{1}{t}\gamma(\int_0^t tf(r)dr)$. However, how to get the result by using quadratic growth condition?

Comment: @Mr.xue The estimate I had in mind was $\gamma(ts) \leq Ct^2 \gamma(s),$ but thinking about it I don't think this will follow from the integral estimate - at least $C$ would depend on $s.$